# Delete files with logrotate

Tags: linux, logrotate

Is it possible JUST to delete the log files in a directory by using logrotate w/o actually rotating them? We have an app that generates logs in the following format: app.log.DD_MM_YYYY. I am unsuccessful with logrotate having the following config:

```
/opt/log/app/app.log.* {
         rotate 0
         missingok
         nomail
}
```

Can log rotate do this or should I just write a script and place it within cron?

Best,
-Iulian

Comment: If you dont need those logs why not disable logging feature on your app?

Comment: I am sorry but I can't count that as an answer Deeh. To feed your curiosity, we need those logs for different operations like debugging, we just don't want to keep them there to rot.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In that case you may want to use postrotate. In the example below postrotate will delete files that are older that 1 day after logs been rotated, feel free to modify it to fit your needs.

```
/opt/log/app/app.log.* {
        missingok
        nomail
postrotate
        /usr/bin/find /opt/log/app/ -name "app.log.*" -type f -mtime +0 -exec rm {} \;
endscript
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of logrotate is to keep a custom number of log files on a custom time interval. I would use cron for your task. More about what you can do with logrotate here: http://www.jamescoyle.net/cheat-sheets/676-logrotate-cheat-sheet

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers to prevent link rot. Instead, add the most relevant information from the link to your answer or alternatively, post the link as a comment instead of an answer. See [this](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) help center article for further information.